# how to track System.out.println in debug mode in complete project

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

There is a project, that I am working on. I am new to that project. Problem is when I click on submit button on certain JSP page, it prints something on console. What ever printed is definitely inside System.out.println(). But I am unable to track that SOP. I also searched that piece of value through search tool in eclipse. But I couldn't find it. Is there any way to do that in debug mode, means can I add breakpoint to my whole project. Guide me. I am stuck.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

Logging is a better way to track SOP kind of things.  Use the Log class to log info about the the app,  it's got Debug, Verbose, Info, Warning and other stuff